# Yii datepicker in gridview filter changes format after ajax request

Tags: php, yii, datepicker, format

like in the subject. I have a `CGridView` and Yii's `datepicker` in one of the filters. I have a format set to `yy-mm-dd` but after I put the value and the `GridView` use ajax to adjust the data - format is changed to: `dd.mm.yy`. Here is my code:

```
array(
        'name' => 'confirmStart',
        'filter' => $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', 
            array(
                'model' => $model,
                'attribute' => 'confirmStart',
                'language' => 'pl',
                'i18nScriptFile' => 'jquery.ui.datepicker-ja.js',
                'htmlOptions' => array(
                    'id' => 'Projects_confirmStart',
                    'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                ),
                'defaultOptions' => array(  // (#3)
          'showOn' => 'focus', 
          'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
          'showOtherMonths' => true,
          'selectOtherMonths' => true,
          'changeMonth' => true,
          'changeYear' => true,
          'showButtonPanel' => true,
      )
            ),
            true),
    ),
```

Comment: Check if your model converts it to this format. What you see in filter field after request is value of ``confirmStart`` field of your ``$model`` after ``$model->search()``.

Comment: I don't think my model does it. In database format is the same and I don't have any converting code in the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if this is gonna solve your problem, but I had some issues when using a datepicker in a CGridView. To solve it I needed to reinstall the datepicker:

In your CGridView:

```
'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'reinstallDatePicker',
```

And below the Cgrid View add the following sript:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('re-install-date-picker', "
    function reinstallDatePicker(id, data) {
        $('#Projects_confirmStart').datepicker();
    }
");
```

If it still doesn't solve your problem you could try:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('re-install-date-picker', "
    function reinstallDatePicker(id, data) {
        $('#Projects_confirmStart').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    }
");
```

or (not sure of the one you should use)

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('re-install-date-picker', "
    function reinstallDatePicker(id, data) {
        $('#Projects_confirmStart').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
    }
");
```

**Edit:**

To put back the date you could try to set the date using javascript:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('re-install-date-picker', "
    function reinstallDatePicker(id, data) {
        $('#Projects_confirmStart').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
        var start = $('#Projects_confirmStart').val();
        $('#Projects_confirmStart' ).datepicker( 'setDate', start );
    }
");
```

I'm really not sure it will work

Comment: Hey! I was using the `({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' })` but it wasn't working. I used the last code from your answer and it works now. I mean - format is not changing. It causes one issue though - after ajax update the date disappears from the field. As I have 3 datepickers would be better if it stays there ;) any idea maybe?

Comment: I updated my answer, but I'm not sure it will work. Please keep me informed!

Comment: Nope. The dollar sign is not working in javascript altough idea is good. If I replace the `$model->confirmStart` with the actual date - it does place the data inside the text area. I just have to figure out how to get the date. Anyway I will accept your answer as my base question is answered by you. Thanks!

Comment: Got it! I added: `var start = $('#Projects_projStart').val(); $('#Projects_projStart' ).datepicker( 'setDate', start );`. Thanks again! Change the code in your answer so anyone that would look at it won't have to read this comment.